# Validate Exceed Input Retry Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, validation

I'm newbie in flutter and wanted to know how to validate that if the user input exceeds the limit retry, it will give an error.

For example, the login page where the user submits the wrong username or password after 3 times retry, will give an error message.
I want to use **`TextFormFields`** for the Email and Password for validation, and button like **`InkWell`** to navigate to the next page if successful.

In my idea, I need to count the wrong input times and do if-else condition where if user exceeds the limit, it will show an error.

My code:

```
InkWell(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          onTap: () {
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              // if user wrongly input 
                              if () {
                                count++; // store wrong times 
                                if (count > 3) {
                                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                      msg:
                                          "You have exceed login retry. Please contact admin.");
                                }
                              } else {
                                print("successful");
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            BottomNavigation()));
                              }
                            }
                          }},
```

Hopefully, someone can help me even if it seems easy from your end. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Srhjhr have a state variable called `timesLogin` and initialize it to 0. and then in your onTap function you can do like this

```
onTap: () {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
         // if user has correct information
         if (timesRun < 3) {
              print("successful");
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomNavigation()));
              } else {
                   //User has reached the threshold
                   Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "You have exceed login retry. Please contact admin.");
              } else {
                //User has input wrong information increase the timesRun value
                timesRun +=1;
                if (timesRun >=3){
                      //User has reached the threshold
                   Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "You have exceed login retry. Please contact admin.");
           }
     }
},
```